How to repack an initramfs cpio archive?
I have unpacked an initramfs cpio archive, and repacked it with sudo find -depth | sudo cpio -o -H newc > ~/repacked_initramfs.cpio, as per: https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/initramfs-tools/-/blob/master/mkinitramfs?ref_type=heads#L492
The repacked_initramfs.cpio is exactly the same size as the original:
~ $ ls -lA initramfs.cpio repacked_initramfs.cpio
-rw-r--r-- 1 fadedbee fadedbee 227892224 Apr  3 15:27 initramfs.cpio
-rw-r--r-- 1 fadedbee fadedbee 227892224 Apr  8 15:32 repacked_initramfs.cpio

The gzipped size is slightly different:
root@smarcimx8mq4g:~# ls -lA initramfs.cpio repacked_initramfs.cpio
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 227892224 Apr  3 14:27 initramfs.cpio
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 227892224 Apr  8 14:32 repacked_initramfs.cpio

root@smarcimx8mq4g:~# gzip initramfs.cpio

root@smarcimx8mq4g:~# gzip repacked_initramfs.cpio 

root@smarcimx8mq4g:~# ls -lA initramfs.cpio.gz repacked_initramfs.cpio.gz 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 68217581 Apr  3 14:27 initramfs.cpio.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 68212934 Apr  8 14:32 repacked_initramfs.cpio.gz

As are the sizes of the .img files:
root@smarcimx8mq4g:~# mkimage -A arm64 -O linux -T ramdisk -n "Initial Ram Disk" -d initramfs.cpio.gz initramfs.img
Image Name:   Initial Ram Disk
Created:      Mon Apr  8 15:29:54 2024
Image Type:   AArch64 Linux RAMDisk Image (gzip compressed)
Data Size:    68217581 Bytes = 66618.73 KiB = 65.06 MiB
Load Address: 00000000
Entry Point:  00000000

root@smarcimx8mq4g:~# mkimage -A arm64 -O linux -T ramdisk -n "Initial Ram Disk" -d repacked_initramfs.cpio.gz repacked_initramfs.img
Image Name:   Initial Ram Disk
Created:      Mon Apr  8 15:30:21 2024
Image Type:   AArch64 Linux RAMDisk Image (gzip compressed)
Data Size:    68212934 Bytes = 66614.19 KiB = 65.05 MiB
Load Address: 00000000
Entry Point:  00000000

root@smarcimx8mq4g:~# ls -lA initramfs.img repacked_initramfs.img 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 68217645 Apr  8 15:29 initramfs.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 68212998 Apr  8 15:30 repacked_initramfs.img

When I boot from the original initramfs, it mounts the real rootfs from the initramfs and I get the expected login prompt:
u-boot$ setenv loadinitrd ext4load mmc ${mmcdev}:2 ${initrd_addr} /root/initramfs.img
u-boot$ setenv mmcboot "echo Booting from mmc ...; run mmcargs; if test ${boot_fdt} = yes || test ${boot_fdt} = try; then if run loadfdt; then run loadinitrd ; booti ${loadaddr} ${initrd_addr} ${fdt_addr}; else echo WARN: Cannot load the DT; fi; else echo wait for boot; fi;"
u-boot$ run bootcmd
Setting bus to 0
1050 bytes read in 13 ms (78.1 KiB/s)
Importing environment from mmc (uEnv.txt)...
30075392 bytes read in 1280 ms (22.4 MiB/s)
49035 bytes read in 20 ms (2.3 MiB/s)
Booting from mmc ...
49035 bytes read in 19 ms (2.5 MiB/s)
68217645 bytes read in 2849 ms (22.8 MiB/s)
## Loading init Ramdisk from Legacy Image at 43800000 ...
   Image Name:   Initial Ram Disk
   Image Type:   AArch64 Linux RAMDisk Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    68217581 Bytes = 65.1 MiB
   Load Address: 00000000
   Entry Point:  00000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 43000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x43000000
   Using Device Tree in place at 0000000043000000, end 000000004300ef8a

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd034]
...
[    7.655738] Freeing unused kernel memory: 3008K
[    7.669121] Run /init as init process
Loading, please wait...
[    7.715755] udevd[246]: starting version 3.2.9
...
smarcimx8mq4g login:

but with the repacked initramfs I see:
u-boot$ setenv loadinitrd ext4load mmc ${mmcdev}:2 ${initrd_addr} /root/repacked_initramfs.img
u-boot$ setenv mmcboot "echo Booting from mmc ...; run mmcargs; if test ${boot_fdt} = yes || test ${boot_fdt} = try; then if run loadfdt; then run loadinitrd ; booti ${loadaddr} ${initrd_addr} ${fdt_addr}; else echo WARN: Cannot load the DT; fi; else echo wait for boot; fi;"
u-boot$ run bootcmd
Setting bus to 0
1050 bytes read in 13 ms (78.1 KiB/s)
Importing environment from mmc (uEnv.txt)...
30075392 bytes read in 1281 ms (22.4 MiB/s)
49035 bytes read in 19 ms (2.5 MiB/s)
Booting from mmc ...
49035 bytes read in 19 ms (2.5 MiB/s)
68212998 bytes read in 2853 ms (22.8 MiB/s)
## Loading init Ramdisk from Legacy Image at 43800000 ...
   Image Name:   Initial Ram Disk
   Image Type:   AArch64 Linux RAMDisk Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    68212934 Bytes = 65.1 MiB
   Load Address: 00000000
   Entry Point:  00000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 43000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x43000000
   Using Device Tree in place at 0000000043000000, end 000000004300ef8a

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd034]
...
[    6.868638] Freeing unused kernel memory: 3008K
[    6.880635] Run /init as init process
[    6.884549] Failed to execute /init (error -2)
[    6.889004] Run /sbin/init as init process
[    6.893169] Run /etc/init as init process
[    6.897247] Run /bin/init as init process
[    6.901328] Run /bin/sh as init process
[    6.905221] Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance.
[    6.919390] CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.10.9 #43
[    6.925394] Hardware name: Embedian SMARC-iMX8M Computer on Module HDMI (DT)
[    6.932440] Call trace:
[    6.932617] usb 3-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci-hcd
[    6.934895]  dump_backtrace+0x0/0x1b0
[    6.945239]  show_stack+0x18/0x68
[    6.948556]  dump_stack+0xd8/0x134
[    6.951957]  panic+0x174/0x33c
[    6.955012]  kernel_init+0xfc/0x118
[    6.958500]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x34
[    6.962078] SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
[    6.966509] Kernel Offset: disabled
[    6.969997] CPU features: 0x0240002,2000200c
[    6.974264] Memory Limit: none
[    6.977324] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance. ]---

I've re-extracted the repacked-initramfs.cpio and proved that /init exists and has identical permissions, ownership and sha1sum as in initramfs.cpio.
What repacking mistake could I be making, which would cause the kernel to not find /init, despite it existing correctly in the repacked_initramfs.cpio?

The sudo on sudo cpio … >output is pointless. If you're already root then you don't need sudo. If you're not root then output can be created by your own account already

@ChrisDavies The sudo is to encure that cpio can read all of the files, whose names it gets from sudo find.  If there was a root-owned file with 600 permissions, my user account would not be able to read it and so it would be missing in the cpio archive.

In your first step do you have find . | LC_ALL=C sort | cpio...? And does that run as root per your reference script or as yourself?

@ChrisDavies Yes, I use sudo find.  I've tried with and without -depth.  (I've just amended the question.)  I don't believe that this is a problem, as in both the original and repackaged cpio archives /init has the correct ownership and permissions.  I don't use a sort.

@ChrisDavies Now I think about it, mkinitramfs does use: LC_ALL=C sort... perhaps the kernel looks for /init in alphabetic order, doesn't find it before /io... and gives up?

That's what I wondered, too, @fadedbee

I added LC_ALL=C sort to my cpio pipeline and now the kernel can run /init from repacked_initramfs.img.
sudo find . | LC_ALL=C sort | sudo cpio -o -H newc > ~/repacked_initramfs.cpio

The kernel must be expecting the initramfs files to be alphanumerically ordered by their full path.  The kernel can't find `/init' if it's out of place.
